# Resources not found in AppCompat

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

I am trying to build an app that was working fine before, but I now get the following message:

> error:resource android:attr/elevation not found

```
error: resource android:attr/elevation not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/elevation not found., sources=[/home/bf/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-19.1.0.aar/8fbac0b82dc50ec174771792ebbf1b1f/res/values/values.xml:508:5-62], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

plus two more.

I tried updating everything and also invalidating caches. When looking in my SDK manager, I see Android Support Library rev23.2.1 is installed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: appcompat-v7-19.1.0.aar looks odd you must use latest support libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the compilation version to Android 5.0 or above. elevation attribute was introduced in 5.0. So Kit-kat build tools will fail.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of the appcompat library? Besides, I do not use that attribute anywhere. Android/Gradle/Studio come up with it himself.

Comment: is any dependencies/Library are using elevation?

Answer (score 0):

the current stable version of the Support Libraries would be `27.1.1` -

and it is being referenced in the `19.1.0` version, at `res/values/values.xml`

you could provide it eg. with `res/values-19/attrs.xml`, for previous APIs - or even `res/values/attrs.xml`, to provide it as the default attributes.

except that the location would then be `attr/elevation` instead of `android:attr/elevation`.

Answer (score 0):

> Android Support Library rev23.2.1 is installed

This not means you used library 23.2.1, check your app module build.gradle file, which should like this:

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'//28.0.0-rc02 is the latest version, at least you should use 21.0 or higher
```